# Is there kind of "attribute" keyword in C++?

Tags: c++, attributes

maybe I missed something, but I'm wondering about the following:

At the [Mozilla Developer Pages about Coding Guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Coding_Style), I read the following:

> Whenever you are retrieving or setting
>   a single value without any context,
>   you should use attributes. Don't use
>   two methods when you could use one
>   attribute. Using attributes logically
>   connects the getting and setting of a
>   value, and makes scripted code look
>   cleaner.
>
> This example has too many methods:
>
> ```
>  interface nsIFoo : nsISupports {
>      long getLength();
>      void setLength(in long length);
>      long getColor(); 
>  };
> ```
>
> The code below will generate the exact
>   same C++ signature, but is more
>   script-friendly.
>
> ```
> interface nsIFoo : nsISupports {
>     attribute long length;
>     readonly attribute long color; 
> };
> ```

What I'm thinking about is the `attribute long length`. I assume that this syntax aucomatically creates getter/setter methods.

- But is that standard-C++ in any way?
- Is this some mozilla specific stuff?
- Where is this defined?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mozilla uses a language called IDL (interface definition language) to define interfaces for objects that are used in multilanguage contexts, such as both C++ and JavaScript.  It compiles down into code in these two languages and therefore allows developers working on the project to have a single definition for their interfaces in as many languages as they'd like.  So no, this isn't standard C++ code; it's something entirely different.

On a related note, interface and readonly aren't C++ keywords either. :-)

Answer (score 5):

This coding guideline applies to IDL, not C++, so no, `attribute` is not part of C++. The guidelines is taking about the C++ signatures that the IDL *generates*.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
interface nsIFoo : nsISupports {
    attribute long length;
    readonly attribute long color; 
};
```

is I<sub>nterface</sub> D<sub>escription</sub> L<sub>anguage</sub> (Used for C++ – Javascript interop). Mozilla has a tool which generates C++ code for this, with usual getter and setter methods.

C++ itself doesn't have an `attribute` keyword.